# Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed the Facebook application, which clones the registration and sign_in part of my web site. The user can either register or sign in to my web site via Facebook. I have created a Simple HTML Page and embedded that page into facebook tab as a iFrame.

When I open the app as admin, its working fine, but when I asked my pal to check it out, it says page cant be loaded and gives this error

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you configured your sever to enable SSL?

Comment: Via a webserver's default configuration in many cases, .HTML files cannot accept HTTP post parameters.

Comment: Can you get a response from your server when its not serving a page from within an iFrame?  IE. can you access pages directly on your server?

Comment: Have you set the facebook page type to be iframe and not FBML?

Comment: From @Will (had posted this comment as an answer): *Are you running the app in sandbox mode?*

Comment: Often this error comes up when Chrome tries to connect to a server, sends its request, and then the server disconnects. This is either a problem with HTTPS, SSL, or simply the webserver at which you have the HTML file hosted. Where is your html file hosted?

Comment: Try this , it might help you . http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

Comment: turn on the server.. :)

Answer (score 12):

Is your friend on the same network as you? This error message is typically one that you get when a firewall is preventing communication.

If there are no firewalls between your friend and the server, then it could also be a firewall on the server, or that the server is configured only to accept certain kinds of connections (which is very normal for a server). Can you tell us anything about your server and how it is configured?