# GCM failing on load testing

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, load-testing

I am developing a push-notification feature for my app using GCM. After lot of reading and help from the internet I made it work in my test environment(less number of clients, 300 users). I released it with a good hope into staging environment(large number of clients, > 5000 users) only to find that it is tremendously failing. I'm getting **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** and I am not getting any sort of response in return(success,failure,canonical_ids etc.).

I thought it is the registration_ids limit and worked on it but still getting the same response in the networks console. I thought bad internet band width/connectivity but that was a dead end too. Please help me out with this. TIA.

PS : Using node.JS to build the push notification feature. Using async-npm to send P.Ns to large number of reg_ids.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the error occurs due to the problems in the internet connection and in the devices you use to connect to the internet. If checking your internet connection or other network devices you may be using does not work, then it might occur if a firewall is preventing communication. It could also be a firewall on the server, or that the server is configured only to accept certain kinds of connections (which is very normal for a server).

You can check these related links:

- [Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229317/error-102-neterr-connection-refused-the-server-refused-the-connection)
- [An XMPP Server for Google Cloud Messaging](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/)

  > Many problems can crop up in corporate networks, since firewalls might block access to the rather unusual port or proxies might interfere with any outgoing traffic. The exception indicates a networking problem on your part – it’s simply getting a timeout. I guess neither Google nor your provider are the problem here. Check your setup and any firewalls (corporate or personal) between you and the outer internet.

Comment: If it is a firewall on a server, It has to block all of the GCM calls. But its not. Its only happening for a large set of clients. I don't have any firewall as such for my internet connection neither do i have ad-blockers to block my http requests. It is working fine only for small number of clients. How can a firewall allow small requests and block when it is large number of clients.